# Set TextBlock Foreground via Storyboard in Universal Windows doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I tried to animate the TextBlock foreground color using Storyboard. It works perfectly in WPF, but it doesn't seems to work in Universal Windows.

Here is my code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <TextBlock x:Name="tbHello" Text="Hello World" FontSize="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0"
                ColorInterpolationMode="ScRgbLinearInterpolation">
                    <GradientStop Color="#ff666666" Offset="-0.2" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#ffffffff" Offset="-0.1" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#ff666666" Offset="0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tbHello"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                                             From="-0.2" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:1.5" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tbHello"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                                             From="-0.1" To="1.6" Duration="0:0:1.5" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tbHello"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                                             From="0" To="1.7" Duration="0:0:1.5" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Any idea why it doesn't work on Universal Windows Platform?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation you have defined is being considered as a [*depended animation*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx#dependent), so as I've tried it will work if you set [EnableDependentAnimation="True"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation.enabledependentanimation.aspx), though as MSDN says - use it with caution.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbHello" Text="Hello World" FontSize="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0"
        ColorInterpolationMode="ScRgbLinearInterpolation">
                <GradientStop Color="#ff666666" Offset="-0.2" />
                <GradientStop Color="#ffffffff" Offset="-0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#ff666666" Offset="0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tbHello" EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                                     From="-0.2" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:1.5" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tbHello" EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                                     From="-0.1" To="1.6" Duration="0:0:1.5" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tbHello" EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                                     From="0" To="1.7" Duration="0:0:1.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You are a champion! Thanks Romasz!